Issue in Pdf download using request module in python
import requests

pdf_url = "https://www.alexandrina.sa.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0028/1619614/Council-Special-Meeting-Agenda-11-June-2024.pdf"
pdf_path = 'Test.pdf'
response = requests.get(pdf_url)
pdf_content = response.content 

with open(pdf_path, 'wb') as pdf_file:
    pdf_file.write(pdf_content)

using this code not able to download pdf because haivng 403 response but when i open it mannualy on chrome it opens and also download in my locals but when i use request module im not able to download or if use any proxy or scrape do it download but it got currupted so i cant access this pdf, can you please help what should i do?

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  My guess is the server is expecting some sort of User Agent or the server has some other check that you're not providing information for.

are you attempting to read the contents or to download a file ?

Seems no issue in your code. I have just changed to another pdf url, it works well.
import os
import requests

save_dir = os.getcwd()
file_name = 'test.pdf'

#url = 'https://www.alexandrina.sa.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0028/1619614/Council-Special-Meeting-Agenda-11-June-2024.pdf'

url2 = 'https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf'


outfile = os.path.join(save_dir, file_name)
response = requests.get(url2, stream=True)
with open(outfile,'wb') as output:
  output.write(response.content)


As someone mentioned here. The pdf source server block downloading using code which can prevent bots.

PDF the web server is providing you with a web page intended to prevent bots from downloading data from the site.


can you try with the same url i have given because i can download any other url with the code but i am having issue with url i given in code

It may be the PDF server block from auto downloading from code. So it may be the build-in error. I have just tried your url, also download an can't-open pdf the same as you
